# Adding a picturebox to a panel

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, picturebox

I have a Windows Forms application containing a panel (called panel1), and a button. I'm trying to add and display a new PictureBox when the button's clicked, but I can't get my code working.

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox picture = new PictureBox();
    picture.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
    picture.Name = "pictureBox1";
    picture.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 50);
    picture.BackColor = Color.Black;
    panel1.Controls.Add(pictureBox1);
}
```

My panel` Dock is set to Fill.

Full code: https://pastebin.com/v73mZ9Ua

-- Update --

I've just realized my mistake: I was using the wrong variable name: panel1.Controls.Add(pictureBox1); when it should be panel1.Controls.Add(picture);

Comment: How large is the panel? Larger than 200x200, I hope?Of course you did actually create the pbox or else you would have gotten a null object reference error, right..? And the pBox has visible=true, right??

Comment: Are you sure `panel1` is defined (i.e. no NullReferenceExceptions)? Are you sure you added the event `button1_Click_1` to the click of that particular button?

Comment: yes i have no compile errors and it runs properly. Yes panel1 is defined .

Comment: Where is `picture` defined? And how large is `panel1`? I just changed your `picture.Location = new Point(200, 200);` to `picture.Location = new Point(0, 0);` and it works for me.

Comment: Just noticed i forgot to set the click event on the actual button.
now i gives me a error Unhandled expection :
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.?

Comment: @RusHrus That's most likely because you don't seem to define `picture` anywhere. At least, not in the code you've provided.

Comment: picture is defined outside the button1_Click_1.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/mCHwzuX.png   See my reference here; that is all of the code and it works as you can see. Unless there's a specific reason you need the `PictureBox` to be a class-level variable, you should move it to the button click event instead. No need to waste resources creating an object during form creation if it won't be needed until you click a button

Comment: @RusHrus Which element throws the null reference exception?

Comment: ok now i define it like that inside the button1_Click_1. :

            private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PictureBox picture = new PictureBox();
            picture.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            picture.Name = "pictureBox1";
            picture.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 50);
            picture.BackColor = Color.Black;
            panel1.Controls.Add(pictureBox1);
        }

Comment: just edited my question check the code , it still doesn't show up. runs without any problems.

Comment: Your code says `panel1.Controls.Add(pictureBox1);`  I think you intended `panel1.Controls.Add(picture);` instead.

Comment: @LarsTech Yep thank you, I just didn't saw that one. now it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PictureBox pictureBox1 = new PictureBox();


        }
     private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(50,50);
            pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
            pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 50);
            pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Black;
            panel1.Controls.Add(pictureBox1);
    }

}
```

Comment: This clearly adds the picture on Form_Load. The OP wants to add the picture on the click of a button.

Comment: @sab669 Not being pedantic, check the edit history. My comment was before the current edit.